# VS2010 C++ solution last built state

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Solutions A and B are similar. 
Work on solution A proceeds to a stop point and is closed.
Work on solution B proceeds and a nice to have patch is developed that would be nice if in solution A.
Solution B is closed.
Solution A is opened.

Why does a complete build of solution A take place even if Debug (F5) is selected before an code changes are applied?

Shouldn't the last built state be present and the re-build not take place?

Is there a VS2010 option to change this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This has been provided as part of VS2010 SP1.
The setting Enable Managed Incremental Build to On corrects this.
Microsoft documentation refers to assemblies which is confusing when
one has used solutions and projects to refer to the working parts of VS2010. 
Here is a link to a graphic of the setting.
http://picpaste.com/Enable_Managed_Incremental_Build-NBbj3Fn1.JPG